# Using the MoMA tool for Mono --- not updated for current Mono version?

Tags: mono

Looking to see if our .net apps are good candidates to run on mono. We believe the MoMA tool is the place to start.

But the MoMA tool, http://mono-project.com/MoMA says it is build on mono 2.8, where the current mono version is 3.2

What is the right way to check if a .net 4.51 app, it is a windows service, will run on mono?